# PyWinAuto still useful?

Tags: python, pywinauto

I've been playing with PyWinAuto today and having fun automating all sorts GUI tests.  I was wondering if it is still state of the art or if there might be something else (also free) which does windows rich client automation better.

Comment: I was wondering a similar thing about "WATSUP" -- http://www.tizmoi.net/watsup/intro.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

pywinauto is great because it's Python.

Perhaps a bit more full featured is [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml), which has a COM server that you can automate (from Python using win32com), and some cool tools, like a "[Window Info](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/au3spy.htm)" utility, which will give you the text (title), class, size, status-bar text, and so on for the window currently under the mouse cursor.

There are some cases where pywinauto is a bit harder to use than AutoIt, and seems a little less polished. One example is automating Inno Setup programs. The Inno Setup "setup.exe" program launches a separate application that actually performs the install, and it's a pain to track this down with pywinauto, but AutoIt makes it easy.

Answer (score 8):

I used to do test automation on our projects with AutoIt but switched over to pywinauto 3 months ago and have been very happy with that decision. There are some rough edges, but I've been able to fill them in with my own supplementary test functions. In addition I find that coding tests and support code in Python is *much* easier and more manageable compared to AutoIt. With Python I have way more powerful options for logging, debugging, documentation, process management and test configuration. For me it was absolutely the right way to go.

Answer (score 4):

New [pywinauto 0.6.0](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/releases/tag/0.6.0) has introduced MS UI Automation support under the hood. So that WinForms, WPF, Qt, Store apps etc. could be automated almost the same way as an old native Win32 application.

Moreover it's possible to use `mouse` and `keyboard` modules out of a window/control context. These modules work on Linux as well!

New module `win32_hooks` is inspired by pyHook and similar libraries, but it doesn't require compilation.

Yeah, this post is a kind of ad. But I just wanna say pywinauto is still useful and I believe it will be even more useful in the future. The developers community currently consists of 2 mature developers and 3 talented students and we have long term plans on Linux and Mac OS X.

P.S. There are some more open source tools:

- [similar tools overview in the pywinauto docs](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#some-similar-tools-for-comparison)
- [UI Automation tools rating by GitHub stars and SO stats](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/wiki/UI-Automation-tools-ratings).